# Automatically pick or exclude commits to different environment branches based on tags

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

In a project hosted in gitlab there are two target environments to deploy to: staging and production.

There is a `dev` branch where all features / bugfixes should be merged to. There are commits that should not (yet) be deployed to production so they should be excluded in some way. Most of the commits should go to staging (but not all).

My idea is to set a tag on each commit for each target environment and automatically pick these commits to the environment branch.

```
commit A <- Tags a.prod, a.staging
commit B <- Tags b.staging 
commit C <- Tags none
commit D <- Tags d.staging
commit E <- Tags e.prod, e.staging
-->
branch PROD with commits A and E
branch STAGING with commits A, B, D, E

later:

commit B <- add Tag b.prod
commit C <- add Tag c.stating
commit D <- add Tag d.prod
--> 
branch PROD with commits A, B, D, E
branch STAGING with commits A, B, C, D, E
```

How can this be implemented with gitlab ci?

Currently I cherry pick the commits to the environment branches. The problem: the environment branches run apart. And It is not automated.

My idea is to branch every release from dev branch and exclude commits via rebase -i or some similar.

That should be automated by setting tags and by using gitlab ci.

So something like git based feature flags would be nice :)

Comment: How do you not get merge conflicts with this setup? Is it not possible to isolate “prod” to a branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you need fine-grain control like this, that means that you would manually put the tags on each commit, so this would not change your manual cherry-picking.

Your branches running appart is normal in this situation as cherry-picking in this random order would lead to different commit histories.

By exemple to go from this :

```
branch PROD with commits A and E
branch STAGING with commits A, B, D, E
```

To this

```
branch PROD with commits A, B, D, E
branch STAGING with commits A, B, C, D, E
```

You can merge the staging `git merge staging` (from prod).